# Django + Angular method PUT and POST not allowed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, request

I refactoring a project with Django/Django-Rest and AngularJS 1.4.9. All my GET requests are working fine, but PUT and POST requests don't. I receive a "405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)" error.

All my http requests were Ajax and worked fine, but I'm changing to $http now and having this trouble. What is wrong?

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myapp', [], function($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'jxcsrf';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
}).run(function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = "application/json";
});
```

**UPDATE** showing the django view (but I think is not a django problem, because worked with ajax)

**The view**

```
class MusicAction(APIView):
    """
    Create a music instance or update the vote field in a music instance.
    """

    permission_classes = (IsAllowedOrAdminOrReadOnly,)

    def get_playlist(self, station, playlist_id):
        try:
            return Playlist.objects.get(station=station, pk=playlist_id, playing="1")
        except Playlist.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError(u'Essa playlist não está em uso.')

    def get_music(self, music_id, playlist_id):
        try:
            obj = Music.objects.get(music_id=music_id, playlist_id=playlist_id)
            return obj
        except Music.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError(u'Essa música já tocou ou não existe.')

    def get_object(self, station_id):
        try:
            obj = Station.objects.get(pk=station_id, is_active=True)
            self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
            return obj
        except Station.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=404)


    def put(self, request, format=None):
        station_id = request.data.get("sid")
        station = self.get_object(station_id)
        playlist_id = request.data.get("pid")
        playlist = self.get_playlist(station, playlist_id)
        music_id = request.data.get('mid')

        music = self.get_music(music_id, playlist_id)
        vote = int(request.data.get("vote"))

        with transaction.atomic():
            total = music.vote
            music.vote = total + vote
            music.save()

            station.last_update = timezone.now()
            station.save()

            if vote > 0:
                Voting.objects.create(voted_by=request.user, music=music)
            else:
                vote = Voting.objects.get(voted_by=request.user, music=music)
                vote.delete()

            serializer = MusicSerializer(music)

            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is the header.

[image: request fail]

Comment: We need to see the Django view code that handles `/musics/vote/`. Presumably it is configured only to accept GET requests.

Comment: You need to configure your Django Views to accept PUT, DELETE, [he is post](https://baxeico.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/put-and-delete-http-requests-with-django-and-jquery/)

Comment: @solarissmoke here is the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using one of the generic views of django rest framework:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

for example, if you'd like to accept get and put use the RetrieveUpdateAPIView:

```
from rest_framework import generics

class MusicAction(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    #code...
```